# How to update surfaceview partially?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have a `surfaceview` in my activity. Initially some circles are drawn using

```
Canvas c = SurfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
```

and

```
SurfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Later on I want to draw on a very small part of the `surfaceview`. I do not want to redraw the whole `surfaceview`. Is it possible to update just the required part?

Answer (score 1):

Use `lockCanvas(Rect dirty)` instead.  Pass in the area you want to redraw.

Note that `dirty` is an in-out parameter.  The Rect may be expanded to cover a larger area, and you need to set every pixel it covers.  So if (for example) SurfaceView no longer has access to the previous pixels, it'll expand Rect to cover the entire surface.

Because SurfaceView is double- or triple-buffered, the implementation will copy chunks of pixels from the previous buffer.  Since the Canvas you get from a SurfaceView is never hardware-accelerated, specifying a dirty rect is often a performance win.

Comment: `Rect dty = new Rect(5,5,50,50);
c = sv.getHolder().lockCanvas(dty);
c.drawARGB(254, 0 , 0, 254);
    sv.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);` I used this code but whole screen turns blue, what is wrong here ?

Comment: What were the contents of Rect after `lockCanvas()` returned?

Comment: If this was the very first frame you've drawn on the SurfaceView's surface, then there are no previous contents to preserve.  Try drawing a full red frame followed by a partial blue frame.

Comment: some drawing was done on entire surfaceview when it was created. i used dirty rectangle code to update it after a user  touch input. could you please provide some working example ?

Comment: as u can see in above code Rect was created just before lockCanvas(), hence it was empty.

Comment: The Rect may be updated by lockCanvas(), which is why I was wondering if it held the same values after the call as it did before the call.  The point at which the Rect was created doesn't matter.  If lockCanvas() expanded the Rect, you have to draw everything it covers.

Comment: so what are you suggesting ?

Comment: I'm suggesting the next step is to look at whether the Rect you're passing into lockCanvas() is being updated.  Just log it after lockCanvas() returns and see what you get in logcat.

Comment: plz bear with me, i am a noob here, could you plz tell me what exactly has to be logged ? could you plz give the code ?

Comment: Get https://github.com/google/grafika .  Look at the "Simple Canvas in TextureView" example.  It uses a dirty rect.